# I want the time left on the map to be displayed on my HUD

Tags: half-life-deathmatch

Is there any console command, setting or trickery to make this happen?

Comment: As far as I know this is only possible by 'calling' this commend through a keybind or a console command: timeleft. There doesn't seem to be a native HUD item for this though

Answer (score 4):

I think (but not sure) this is a server or mod option as when I was trying to practice (little good it did), sometimes it was displayed in one of the top corners.

The only way I know of to do it yourself is to go in to `options` > `keyboard`, and then map a key to `Time Remaining` or similar. When you press this key, it displays (near chat/text) how much time is remaining.

Comment: The thing you first described is likely a server mod.  I know SourceMod has the advertisements mod that can do this.